# emulate shared hosting load

Tags: freebsd, shared-hosting, load-testing

I want to emulate some shared-hosting activity in testing environment. Is particularly interested I/O performance. Need to emulate: many sql queries, http queries, and some additional activity, extracting large archive for example.

Comes to mind only creating full copy of shared-hosting server, all sites, with all bases and write some daemon for parsing access.log and perform requests from it. But even in this case there are difficulties: need to copy a thousand sites, many queries in log at any second, must be provided POST queries, not only GET, need to be authorized on dozens of sites (some heavy queries produced by operation in administrative section of sites.)

Maybe there is a ready solution for this test?

Operating system of test platform: FreeBSD

**UPD:** purpose of the test - compare the performance of the system with different mysql solution and different configuration of RAID (usual mirror and hybrid mirror ).

Comment: Setup some shared accounts with websites that have backend DBs then run iperf, and set a cron to extract and delete the files/folder. That's pretty simple/

Comment: @Jacob some any accounts with some any websites will not give sufficient load to I/O. But thanks you, perhaps simple test will give some figures for analysis.

Comment: How would they not? Iperf would simulate the clients which would cause up I/O load.

Comment: @Jacob with increasing load on the disk subsystem i usually see many SELECT queries to databases, but i do not know which comes first: I/O load, or the number of requests. Maybe there is some magically queries to specific bases. Normal queries to ordinary sites will be processed too quickly.

Comment: So engineer the load. If you want to test reality then setup standard site s like wordpress or drupal. If you want to engineer load write than execute queries that are intensive.